# SQL secondary headers within data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue that I haven't found an answer to.  I wrote an SQL Query to generate a report that runs fine and outputs mostly numeric fields.  The issue I'm running into is that we are putting it into a program that emails out files and it can only email out a .csv that does not include the header rows.

Is there a way to input the headers into the data? I've found a few solutions on here that didn't work for me.   It seems like no matter what I do I get a data type error.   This is all on an Oracle Database, the program we are using to send data out is called IQAlert, it's part of IQMS which is a manufacturing/erp system.

So far I've tried casting the headers as a number of numerical fields, a number of other solutions I found on here and other places on the internet such as changing to titles to varchar.  The error I'm currently getting is

> "ORA-01790: expression must have the same datatype as corresponding
>   expression"

Here is an extremely parsed down sample of the code.  Adding the title "itemno' works fine because that field is text, when I try to add the header to onhand I get the data type error referenced above.

```
select 'itemno' as itemno, 'OnHand' as OnHand
from iqms.arinvt

union

select  arinvt.itemno, arinvt.onhand
from iqms.arinvt

where itemno='10-00000000'
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far. Also include the error message(s).

Comment: Added a few changes to the request.  I've been messing with this for a while now so I don't remember everything I've tried.

Comment: A .csv is text. Why do you need to put the headers 'into' data and as numeric? Can't you simply add a comma separated list of headers to your .csv. If it needs to be "in data" then common format is character, cast all your fields as varchar.

Comment: show us your code and sample data. we cannot read the codes without you posting it.

Comment: Cetin, I need headers when the report is mailed out.  The program that is emailed was programmed to not grab the headers and it is recreating the file every time it emails out. I don't have the option of adding the headers to the file.

Comment: âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I added a sample of the code, really appreciate your help!

Comment: what's the datatype of `arinvt.onhand`?

Comment: Kaushik, it is some kind of numeric value, most likely an integer.

Comment: Can't you select headers separately, I mean i don't know the tool you are using, but if you can just do `select 'column1','column2','column3'  
 FROM DUAL ; `  and then run your normal query to get the records, would it work for you?. I'm asking  this because casting all the columns to match the datatype in your query would be simply unnecessary.

Comment: Kaushik, I still get the data type issue with that one because I am trying to add a text header above a number.  I added an example with the code you gave above. So far the only thing I've found that works is converting all the numbers to varchar and then they output as text which isn't ideal.  That fixes the data type issue because everything is text instead of some text and some numbers.  I haven't successfully been able to convert the text headings to the numeric field which is what I think I really need to do.

Comment: @kevin : you didn't understand what I said. I told u to run select from dual as a separate statement , not union all with your select from table. Why do you want to convert the strings to numbers. You're really going down the rabbithole with that approach. Don't do it as it's totally unnecessary

Comment: @KaushikNayak it is because the code is going into a program that drops the headers.  I can't modify that program only my code.  Because the program drops the headers I need to create my own set that are part of the data.

Comment: I don't follow, if you are able to edit this query, then you should be able to add another select statement ( from dual) i suggested above this `select`.  I don't see why  it can't be done, if you are in a position to change the select query.

Comment: @KevinK, I don't think it is possible to have numeric values that appear as text (e.g. `OnHand` as a numeric value). I realize that having numeric values converted to CHAR isn't idea but if the problem is formatting, you may want to look into the masks you can use with the `TO_CHAR()` function. Also if your client is just going to import the CSV into Excel, I believe Excel will format numeric values appropriately whether they were exported as text or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation regarding [The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341)

> You can combine multiple queries using the set operators UNION, UNION
>   ALL, INTERSECT, and MINUS. All set operators have equal precedence. If
>   a SQL statement contains multiple set operators, then Oracle Database
>   evaluates them from the left to right unless parentheses explicitly
>   specify another order.
>
> The corresponding expressions in the select lists of the component
>   queries of a compound query must match in number and must be in the
>   same data type group (such as numeric or character).
>
> If component queries select character data, then the data type of the
>   return values are determined as follows:
>
> - If both queries select values of data type CHAR of equal length, then
>     the returned values have data type CHAR of that length. If the queries
>     select values of CHAR with different lengths, then the returned value
>     is VARCHAR2 with the length of the larger CHAR value.
> - If either or both of the queries select values of data type VARCHAR2,
>     then the returned values have data type VARCHAR2.
>
> If component queries select numeric data, then the data type of the
>   return values is determined by numeric precedence:
>
> - If any query selects values of type BINARY_DOUBLE, then the returned
>     values have data type BINARY_DOUBLE.
> - If no query selects values of type BINARY_DOUBLE but any query selects
>     values of type BINARY_FLOAT, then the returned values have data type
>     BINARY_FLOAT.
> - If all queries select values of type NUMBER, then the returned values
>     have data type NUMBER.
>
> In queries using set operators, Oracle does not perform implicit
>   conversion across data type groups. **Therefore, if the corresponding
>   expressions of component queries resolve to both character data and
>   numeric data, Oracle returns an error.**

---

**In short:** in a query using one of the SET operators, for example like this:

```
SELECT x FROM table
UNION
SELECT y FROM table
```

where `x` is of numeric datatype, and `y`is of character datatype (or vice versa), then Oracle does not perform implicit conversion across data type groups and returns an error
Two simple examples:

```
SELECT 1 as X FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'John' as Y FROM dual

ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

---

```
SELECT 'John' as X FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 123 as Y FROM dual;

ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

---

Because Oracle does not perform implicit conversion, **you must do an explicit conversion of one datatype to another datatype**, the easiest one is to convert numbers to strings using [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions217.htm) conversion function, like in this example:

```
SELECT 'John' as X FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(123) as Y FROM dual;

X   
----
John
123
```

Comment: Thank you for laying that out, it makes perfect sense.  Is there a way to convert the 'John' to a numerical field rather than make all my numbers into text?

Comment: Well, everything is possible, just tell me what are the rules for replacing `John` with a number, for example `John`' is 14567, and `Jane` is  e.g. 8887, and `Tom` is 9354, while `New Your` is 8557 etc.

Comment: But there is no way to have them remain as readable words and convert them to a numeric field?

Comment: I think that it is no possible, but you may ask a separate question "how to convert strings  like `John` and `Jane` to numbers keeping them still readable as `John` and `Jane`", experts from Stack Overflow may find some solution.

Comment: I'll try that.  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. The first number is just sequence, the ROWNUM or ROW_NUMBER() can be used instead. The rest of numbers is simulated values:

```
SELECT itemno, onhand FROM
 (
  select 1 row_seq, NULL itemno, to_number(null) onhand from dual
  union all
  select 2, '5', 6 from dual
  union all
  select 3, '7', 8 from dual
 )
WHERE row_seq > 1
/
```

Output:

```
ITEMNO  ONHAND
5            6
7            8
```

Comment: That won't work because I really need to sets of headers since the actual header is being dropped by the csv program.

Comment: @Kevin K - Sorry, I do not understand. What is sets of headers? I exported and copied the output from csv file. Create your sample, fake data, similar to mine and the desired output.

Comment: I'm using a program to email out the csv file, the issue is that the program leaves the headers behind so I really need to have two sets of headers...the system generated ones and a "header" that is actually part of the data.

Comment: @Kevin K - Well, maybe this is not Oracle issue then? If you run your SQL, save the output into csv then what headers have to do with email? Sorry, it is probably me...

Comment: @Kevin K - one more thing. What is "to sets of headers" in your first comment. Did you mean two sets of headers? What is the output you need. Show the output with fake data.